# Extract numeric part from a string in PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a text like:

```
FHUGBGH(4545496),DFHGUFG(5464564),GFUEIFG(456)
```

I want to remove all non-digit characters and concatenate the resulting numbers with a commas. The output should be:

```
4545496,5464564,456
```

No brackets or anything, only the numeric part separated with commas.

I tried using `replace`, `regexp_replace` etc. but was not successful.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there is exactly *one* comma (among other characters) between each string of digits and no leading or dangling commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/pgSQL or just plain SQL, the expression is the same. Using [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

If exactly one comma is guaranteed between each string of digits and nowhere else:

```
regexp_replace (txt, '[^\d,]', '', 'g')
```

If we can't rely on that:

```
trim(regexp_replace (txt, '\D+', ',', 'g'), ',')
```

[`\d` .. class shorthand for `\[\[:digit:\]\]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) - only digits
`\D` .. the counterpart: `[^[:digit:]]` - everything except digits
`'g'` .. the forth parameter is *required* to replace "globally" and not just the first match.

Demo:

```
SELECT regexp_replace (txt, '[^\d,]', '', 'g')          AS nr1
     , trim(regexp_replace (txt, '\D+', ',', 'g'), ',') AS nr2
FROM  (VALUES ('FHUGBGH(4545496),DFHGUFG(5464564),GFUEIFG(456)')) t(txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
declare
   l_text      varchar2 (100) := 'FHUGBGH(4545496),DFHGUFG(5464564),GFUEIFG(456)';
begin
   dbms_output.put_line (regexp_replace (l_text, '[^,0-9]', ''));
end;
```

PL/SQL block executed

4545496,5464564,456

Edit, I just noticed the Postgres flag.  You probably meant PQSQL not PLSQL which is Oracle RDBMS. I hope it works similar.